# How can I effectively log the arguments of the last function (in src code) automatically in the case of an Error being thrown?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, google-cloud-functions, trace

I'm pretty much at a loss when I look at live server errors and view the stack trace.

E.g. Firebase cloud functions stack trace can point me to a function name and file of where the error had happened.

> at Object.exports.functionName (/user_code/lib/routes/file.js:98:11)

Although sometimes these errors can be hard to reproduce locally without knowing what went wrong with large objects being passed in the request.

```
const requestData = {
    largeData: {
         thatIsNestedManyLevels: undefined // <-- this undefined value causing server error and is hard to guess/reproduce locally 
    }
    // etc..
}
```

So my main focus now is to create a solution that can allow me to snapshot all of the closest top function arguments and include it in the error event.

I also know that firebase's function's console will stop at a certain level and give a "[object object]".

So I may even dedicate a new project to saving these errors and create a browser app that lets me just open/play with the object in the chrome console. (since you can keep on unwrapping the object there).

I feel like though that this is a very common problem and that a solution already exist for it, and hope someone can point me to them.

Question: How can I effectively log the arguments of the last function (in src code) automatically in the case of an Error being thrown?

Comment: Not sure if it plays well with GCF, but you could take a look at the options given by the [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs#local).

Comment: It seems doable, but not feasible. I envision two approaches: a) by using `window.onerror`; b) wrapping functions. The former won't provide information about the caller context, so it's rather an impossible approach. The latter is about wrapping all your targeted functions so you could catch them on their context, but it's a rather too complex and cumbersome solution.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure, there is no in-built method for that. You COULD start with global object and try to wrap every function using something like Proxy, but this seems to be unnecessarily complex. What you usually want is to set up a proper logging system which will log arguments of every function along with other important information, which you can use together with stack trace to track a bug.

Answer (score 1):

On a node application you can define a `__stack` object that will help you get the full stack trace in a logger, like so:

```
global.logger = require(path.join(__dirname, 'app_modules/logger'));
Object.defineProperty(global, '__stack', {
    get: function () {
        let orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = function (_, stack) {
            return stack;
        };
        let err = new Error;
        Error.captureStackTrace(err, arguments.callee);
        let stack = err.stack;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
        return stack;
    }
});
```

Then in the logger module you can call it like this:

```
let logString = JSON.stringify({
                "Level": "Error",
                "LogErr": logEntry,
                "Stacktrace": __stack,
                "at": __stack[1].getFileName() + ":" + __stack[1].getLineNumber() + ":" + __stack[1].getColumnNumber()
            }, null, 4);
            process.stderr.write(
                logString.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")
            );
```